# Issue in rounding off the values extracted from Teradata SQL assistant

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding, teradata

I need to round off couple of fields that I extract from Teradata SQL assistant. 
Currently I am using CAST(Field1 as numeric(20,2)) as Field1
18.529 is rounded to 18.53 but 36.425 is rounded to 36.42 instead I am expecting 36.43
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rounding rules for CASTs depend on a global setting, *RoundHalfwayMagUp* in dbscontrol.

You might try the ROUND function which defaults to the rounding rules you prefer:

```
ROUND(36.425,2)
```

Comment: It worked!!36.425 is rounded to 36.430 now and using regex truncating zeros were removed

Comment: If you don't want trailing zeroes simply cast the column as a `NUMBER`: `ROUND(CAST(36.425 AS NUMBER),2)

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if @dnoeth's response solved your question. #etiquette

Answer (score 1):

I found an old post on a forum [here](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/how-to-use-round-function-in-teradata) which states that the `RoundHalfwayMagUp` controls whether .5 rounds up or down. See [the docs](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Utilities/B035_1102_109A/DBScontrol.14.734.html#ww15141404) for more info

Comment: RoundHalfwayMagUp is a db setting and hence it applies to the entire database. Also the server needs to be restarted for the change to take in effect. So not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

because in 36.425, 5 is near to 0 not to 10,
if you put 36.426 it will round of to 36.43

Round :

It will work like below

between 0 and 5 > increment by 0( replaced )

between 5 to 10 > increment by 1 ( replaced)